# MVVM Light - How to detect if some property has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

How can I detect if some property has changed, but I don't want to subscribe PropertyChanged event. I want to set `HasChanges` before PropertyChanged event is raised.

```cs
public class PatientVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly PatientEntity _entity;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _entity.Id;
        set => Set(ref _entity.Id, value);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _entity.Name;
        set => Set(ref _entity.Name, value);
    }

    public bool HasChanges { get; set; }
}
```

My project type is: WPF App (.NET Framework 4.6)

Comment: Where is `Set` method defned? Why not set `HasChanges` there?

Comment: [`Set` method](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/ViewModelBase.cs) comes from MVVM Light framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `RaisePropertyChanged` method from `ViewModelBase` class, since it's virtual, according to [source code](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/ViewModelBase.cs), and set `HasChanges` property in this method. If you want to track changes before `PropertyChanged` actually, use the `PropertyChanging` event, it's raised before property is set to new value in a `Set` method, according to the sources again

```cs
#if !PORTABLE && !SL4
    RaisePropertyChanging(propertyName);
#endif
    field = newValue;
    // ReSharper disable ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    // ReSharper restore ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
```

Comment: `override` is what I need. There are 4 overloads of this method, but in my tests it turned out that this is always called: `public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null);`

Comment: I don't have PropertyChanging event in ViewModelBase class. Project type: WPF App (.NET Framework 4.6)

Comment: @marbel82 because it's declared in [ObservableObject](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/ObservableObject.cs) class, which is inherited by ViewModelBase

Comment: I use ILSpy and open `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll`. I don't have PropertyChanging in my version of this library. I created [an issue on GitHub #77](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/issues/77) but the [author does not respond](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/issues/69)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply subscribe to the `PropertyChanging` event which is implemented in the `ViewModelBase` base class.

```
public PatientVm()
{
    PropertyChanging += (e => HasChanges = true);
}
```

Comment: OP explicitly said that he don't want to subscribe PropertyChanged event.

Comment: I don't have PropertyChanging event in ViewModelBase class. Project type: WPF App (.NET Framework 4.6)

Comment: @marbel82 `ViewModelBase` should inherit it from `ObservableObject` (which you also should probably use for your entities/DTOs instead of exposing every property again in the ViewModel).

https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/ObservableObject.cs#L60
(It's only disabled for Portable and Silverlight, but the .NET Framework version should include it)

Comment: I use ILSpy and open `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll`. I don't have PropertyChanging in my version of this library. I created [an issue on GitHub #77](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/issues/77) but the [author does not respond](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/issues/69)